# Web Forms For Marketers on Content Delivery missing index.cshtml on Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: wffm, installation, packages

We have installed WFFM on a Content delivery server and we were following the official documentation the Sitecore website. After installation we saw that the `index.cshtml` was not deployed in the views folder on the Content delivery server.

We checked the installation package for the CD role and found out the `index.cshtml` was not in the package also.

The package we are using is: Web Forms for Marketers 9.0 rev. 171209_cd.scwdp

How to fix the issue of the missing `index.cshtml`?

Comment: How did you install the WFFM module? Did you use the module zip package or the wdp files for Azure AppService?

Comment: I vaguely remember seeing this when installing using the zip package. If I am not mistaken, we copied the v8.2 index.cshtml file and used it which worked well. Did you give this method a try?

Comment: @jammykam added the package name in the description (Web Forms for Marketers 9.0 rev. 171209_cd.scwdp)

Comment: @navneet pisharodi, we thought of such solution but it would be a work-around for the real issue.

Comment: And to confirm, you are running your CD servers on Azure PaaS?

Comment: @jammykam that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error with the Azure wdp packages that are available for download from the Sitecore Developer site.

If you open up the downloaded zip, e.g. *Packages for XM Scaled.zip*, and inspect the contents using an application such as [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) you will notice that the `Content\Website\Views\Form` folder is empty and contains no files:

[image: WFFM CD wdp]

For the exact same version of WFFM, if you check the cswdp.zip package for the CM instance then you will see that the Views exists as would expect.

[image: WFFM CM wdp]

To resolve the error, you can repacked the CD wdp with the missing files (you should be able to replace the entire `Content` folder) and use that for your deployments.

You should also raise this issue with Sitecore Support to fix since the original packages have been generated incorrectly.

Comment: Can you confirm this is an error, is there any information available from the side of sitecore?

Comment: This is the error, but I don't have anything official from Sitecore I'm afraid, which is why I suggested raising a Support ticket. If you read the installation guide (which i grant is for the regular zip) then that also talks about extracting/copying all the files from the `Files` folder to `Website`